# Linq to SQL - Delete Child Property

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to delete a child property of a domain entity. In the UI, the user selects Delete to remove a `CustomVariableGroup` from an `Application` entity.

I thought deleting the property from the LINQ-to-SQL entity & then submitting changes, would cause LINQ-to-SQL to take care of the work on the Database side. But the row never gets deleted from the table. When I refresh the page in my application, the property is still there because it's still there in the Database.

```
public void Save(Application application)
{
    ApplicationRecord appRecord = application.Map();  // Maps domain entity to L2S entity

    // Before this line executes, appRecord has 0 CustomVariableGroups, which is correct.
    this.Database.ApplicationRecords.Attach(appRecord, true);
    // After the attach, appRecord now has 1 CustomVariableGroup again. This is wrong.

    appRecord = application.Map();  // Hack to remove the CustomVariableGroup again.

    // This doesn't delete the CustomVariableGroup from appRecord. Do I need
    // to delete it explicitly? Or should removing it from appRecord, and
    // calling SubmitChanges() do it?
    this.Database.SubmitChanges();
}
```

What is the right way for me to get rid of this child property on the entity? I guess I could loop through the list and delete each item individually, but I don't think LINQ-to-SQL is supposed to work that way.

Any ideas are appreciated.

**Note:** The property `ApplicationCustomVariableGroupRecords` represents a table that resolves a `many-to-many` association in the Database. An `Application` can have one or more `CustomVariableGroups`, and a `CustomVariableGroup` can belong to one or more `Applications`.

Comment: I don't actually see the Submit call in your screenshot, shouldn't there be a this.DataBase.ApplicationRecords.Submit() ?

Comment: I just posted the entire Save() method. There is a Submit() call, but on the Database, not on ApplicationRecords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you have to specifically delete the object - removing it from a parent collection just means you don't want it to be associated with that particular parent anymore.  It can't tell that you don't want to then associate it with a different parent.  If you want it to get deleted, you need to make the call to have it deleted (DeleteOnSubmit for L2S, IIRC)

Comment: So, if I have a parent (Foo) with a list of 14 child entities (Bar), do I have to explicitly delete each Bar that the user selected to remove? That can be a little tricky, especially since I'm dealing with a domain entity that was mapped from the L2S entity when it was originally retrieved from the data layer. That means I'll have to compare the lists of the original Bars and the new Bar list to see which need to be deleted.

Comment: assuming you want all those Bar instances to be deleted from the database instead of associated with different parents, then yes.  You can do DeleteAllOnSubmit instead of a foreach (bar) DeleteOnSubmit, but yes, you need to delete them.  Note that this is assuming it's a 'normal' parent-child relationship (2 tables) and not a n:m (with an intermediate mapping table), so if I'm misinterpreting, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

if im not wrong the tables which have n to n relations between them are works like nested..So try to first delete from the 3rd table (which contains IDs of 2 table) and then remove from main table..

[Sorry, i can't see add comment button on the page.. so i wrote this idea as answer ]

Comment: Your answer works, but the James' answer was a bit more appropriate.

Comment: @BobHorn sure :)) James has much more experience than me.. With him and other experts we learn better ways which we already knew.. thank to him.. with his answer i learned one thing more :)